# Return by immigration officials

Tags: customs-and-immigration, south-africa, return

I was returned from entering SA by a immigration officer because I couldn’t show them funds in my account and my passport was stamped and (ADMISSION APPLIED FOR) was written in it. What does that mean?

Answer (score 4):

You presented yourself at the South Africa border, seeking to enter South Africa.

After examining you, South Africa immigration refused to allow you to enter South Africa.

This is a "Refusal of Entry." It is not a "visa refusal" nor is it a "deportation."

Answer (score 2):

It means you've been sent home for not meeting entry requirements, you've been denied entry into the country.

It does NOT mean you can't attempt to get in again once you've met those entry requirements.

In short, the border agent was not convinced you'd be able to support yourself during your stay in the country without resorting to working without a work permit or committing some other crime, therefore you were returned to your point of origin. He did not consider this important enough to deny you future entry into the country by blacklisting you from future entry.

So once you get the money together so you can show you can support yourself during your stay you're probably free to enter (unless of course there are by then other factors to deny you, let's hope that's not the case).